# Zuul proxy - how to forward requests to services depending on request path

Tags: java, spring, reverse-proxy, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

## Problem

How to forward requests in Spring Cloud application? I need to forward requests to other services depending on the part of uri.

For example

- `HTTP GET http://user-application/api/users`, returns users JSON.
- `HTTP GET http://user-application/api/proxy/jobs-application/api/jobs`, returns jobs JSON, but this request should be forwarded to another application:
  `HTTP GET http://jobs-application/api/jobs`.

  - Any HTTP method is allowed, not only `GET`.

## Context

I have a SpringBoot Application, **User application** which has REST end-points which return data.

For example `GET http://user-application/api/users` would return users in the JSON format.

**User application** also has an HTTP end-point which should forward the request to other applications - let's call one of them **Jobs application**.

This end-point is `HTTP {ANY_METHOD} /api/proxy/{dynamic-service}/{dynamic-path}` as an example,
`GET http://user-application/api/proxy/jobs-application/api/jobs`

Please, note, initial request comes to the **User application**, while then it is forwarded to the **Jobs application**.

## Approaches

I put some my approaches which I think about. Maybe you have done similar things in the past, so you could share your experience doing so. Or even improve one of my approaches.

### ProxyController approach

I would create a `ProxyController` in **User application** with mapping `/proxy`

```
@Controller
@RequestMaping("/proxy/**")
ProxyController

public void proxy(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
    final String requestUri = request.getRequestUri();
    if (!requestUri.startsWith("/api/proxy/")) {
        return null; // Do not proxy
    }

    final int proxyIndex = "/api/proxy/".lenght(); // Can be made a constant
    final String proxiedUrl = requestUri.subString(proxyIndex, requestUri.lenght());

    final Optional<String> payload = retrievePayload(request);
    final Headers headers = retrieveHeaders(request);

    final HttpRequest proxyRequest = buildProxyRequest(request, headers);
    payload.ifPresent(proxyRequest::setPayload);
    final HttpResponse proxyResponse = httpClient.execute(proxyRequest)
    pdateResponse(response, proxyResponse);
}
```

The problem with this approach, I have to write a lot of code t build a proxy request, to check if it has payload and if it has, copy it into proxy request, then copy headers, cookies etc to the proxy request, copy HTTP verb into proxy request. Then when I get proxy response, I have to populate its details into the response.

### Zuul approach

I was inspired by ZuulFilters:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-with-zuul-proxy
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856576/4587961

```
@Component
public class ProxyFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final String PROXY_PART = "/api/proxy";
    private static final int PART_LENGTH = PROXY_PART.length();

    @Autowired
    public ProxyFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        final RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        final String requestURI = retrieveRequestUri(context);
        return requestURI.startsWith(PROXY_PART);
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        final RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        final String requestURI = retrieveRequestUri(context);
        final String forwardUri = requestURI.substring(PART_LENGTH);
        context.setRouteHost(buildUrl(forwardUri));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "proxy";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    private String retrieveRequestUri(final RequestContext context) {
        final HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
        return request.getRequestURI();
    }

    private URL buildUrl(final String uri) {
        try {
            return new URL(uri);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to forward request uri %s}.", uri), e);
        }
    }
}
```

This code allows me to forward requests with less effort. However, we also use client side load balancer Ribbon and circuit breaker Hystrix in Spring Cloud Zuul out of box. How to enable these features? Will they be enabled out of box in `context.setRouteHost(forwardUrl);`

Comment: Hi, I tried your second approach, but it says Request method 'POST' not supported; Request does not reach the zuul filter.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another approach, maybe it can also work.

### Static application.yml file to configure Zuul proxy approach

This approach does not requre dynamic Zuul Filters.

application.yml

```
zuul:
  routes:
    user-application:
      path: /api/users/**
      serviceId: user-service
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:

    #  I have to define all other services similarly.

    jobs-application:
      path: /api/proxy/jobs/**
      serviceId: jobs-application
      stripPrefix: true
      sensitiveHeaders:
```

It will work only if I know all the services my clients need to call before I deploy the **User application**. What if a new application is added dynamically? Then I will have to update the configuration.